# Getting Google API Push Notifications for Resources/Rooms

Tags: google-calendar-api

I'm trying to get Google Calendar Push Notifications working for Resources (aka Rooms). They work perfectly for user calendars, but when I call/watch on a Resource, it successfully creates. I get the initial "Sync" call on the server, but then I never hear back from Google again.

My approach to creating the watch is to authenticate an administrator, and use that Token to add the watch on the resource that the administrator had added as a calendar to his list, so it's showing up in the calendarList/list call. I've also turned on all notifications on the admin's account for that calendar.

Any idea on what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you register the domain of your receiving URL. If you plan to use `https://domain.com/notifications` as your receiving URL, you need to register `https://domain.com.` Each watchable Google Calendar API resource has an associated `watch` method at a URI of the following form:

`https://www.googleapis.com/apiName/apiVersion/resourcePath/watch`

You need to send a POST request to the watch method for the resource to set up a notification channel for messages about changes to a particular resource.

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/my_calendar@gmail.com/events/watch
Authorization: Bearer auth_token_for_current_user
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "id": "01234567-89ab-cdef-0123456789ab", // Your channel ID.
  "type": "web_hook",
  "address": "https://domain.com/notifications", // Your receiving URL.
  ...
  "token": "target=myApp-myCalendarChannelDest", // (Optional) Your channel token.
  "expiration": 1426325213000 // (Optional) Your requested channel expiration time.
  }
}
```

Each notification channel is associated both with a particular user and a particular resource (or set of resources). A `watch` request will not be successful unless the current user owns or has permission to access this resource.

Check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push#making-watch-requests).

Comment: Yep, I've done all of this. I also get the initial sync message from google, but then I never get another hit no matter what I do to the resource. I've done exactly the same thing with my own calendar, and it works perfectly, so it doesn't appear to be an issue with API calls, but with some other setting possibly?

Comment: Ack.. I just tried it again, and of course, it works now. I'm going to say it's internet magic, but your answer was right on, so I'm marking it as correct. Thank you!